# ORA-24813: cannot send or receive an unsupported LOB

Tags: oracle

I actually want create table script in oracle, for which I searched and found some SQL in below link,
[How can I generate (or get) a ddl script on an existing table in oracle? I have to re-create them in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26249892/how-can-i-generate-or-get-a-ddl-script-on-an-existing-table-in-oracle-i-have)

Which is as,

```
SQL> set long 100000 
SQL> set head off 
SQL> set echo off 
SQL> set pagesize 0 
SQL> set verify off
SQL> set feedback off 
SQL> select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'EMP') from dual
```

But after executing this in SQL CMD I am getting error as below,

> ORA-24813: cannot send or receive an unsupported LOB

Please tell me how I can get the DDL

Comment: This message usually indicates that you're running an ancient version of Oracle server or client. So what versions are you running? Let's hope it's the client which is too old, as the solution is to upgrade the obsolete software.

Comment: THanks i'll check this...