# How to get create table script of existing in oracle 10g using Query

Tags: java, oracle, oracle10g

I want create same table in other schema, for which i want get create table script of existing in oracle 10g using Query

Please tell me how to get it..

Comment: Why is this question tagged java?

Comment: [You already seem to know how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47322626/266304)?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a SQL statement, you can use the dbms_metadata package

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl( 'TABLE', 'EMP', 'SCOTT' )
from dual;
```